# Facebook Auth TypeError: "bool" is read-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, mern

I'm working on a MERN api app.  While working on the front-end which is separate, I keep getting this error which I believe is restricting me from using conditional rendering on the React side of things.  I get *mostly* the same login page, but once I've logged in the FB login button does not change to a log out button, and the `<h1>` saying I'm logged in does not render either.

I'm getting the correct Auth response from loginForm.js, so I am logged in with FB and it recognizes that, but doesn't conditionally render in React.

Unfortunately it's an anonymous function so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  This is what it shows in the console:

```
function g(a) {
                            a.__wrapper || (a.__wrapper = function() {
                                try {
                                    return a.apply(this, arguments)
                                } catch (a) {
                                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                                        throw a
                                    }, 0);
                                    return !1
                                }
                            });
                            return a.__wrapper
                        }
```

In the loginForm.js file :

```
...
render() {
    const loginStatus = <div>Loading</div>

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        return loginStatus = (
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <h1>You logged in lol</h1>
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        return loginStatus = (
            <div>
                (normal login form with a button for FB login, which renders correctly when I'm not logged into FB)
            </div>
        )

return loginStatus
...
```

index.html (html template for Webpack prod build)

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"
    src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v9.0&appId=<my App Id, actual ID is in the file>&autoLogAppEvents=1"
    nonce="bOzvorGV"></script>
  <div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<my App Id, actual ID is in the file>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v9.0'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };
      (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Any ideas of what causes this error? I can provide more code if needed, sorry I'm still learning a lot right now and so far google and bing haven't showed any similar questions with this error.

Comment: inside render function you have to return something, whereas you are just calling a function. Call the function, then return your div if true and return null if false.

Comment: @SinanYaman Sorry I edited the post for clarity, I do have the return values set.  It renders the normal login form which should only be rendering when logged out.  It doesn't render the FB button though since I am logged in.  The console.log also shows the logged in response from FB so I am logged in.